# How to get a block of values out of a terra raster?

Tags: raster, terra

How to reproduce, for `terra` rasters, the function `getValuesBlock` of the `raster` package? For example, how to translate into the `terra` package the example given in the documentation of the getValuesBlock of the `raster` package?

```
logo <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
getValuesBlock(logo, row=35, nrows=3, col=50, ncols=3, lyrs=2:3)
```

I can write:

```
logoT <- rast(logo*1)
Cells <- rep(50:(50+3-1),3)+rep(((35-1):(35-1+3-1))*ncol(logoT),each=3)
extract(logoT[[2:3]], Cells)
```

But the formula is not so easy to find and prone to script errors. Is there a more direct equivalent in `terra`?

Answer (score 1):

You can now use `terra::values`

```
x <- values(logoT, row=35, nrows=3, col=50, ncols=3, mat=TRUE)
head(x)
#     red green blue
#[1,] 155   168  220
#[2,] 167   176  231
#[3,] 165   175  226
#[4,] 154   167  219
#[5,] 165   176  230
#[6,] 165   175  226
```

But you cannot specify the layers you want, unlike with `raster::getValuesBlock`

If you have coordinates rather than row/col numbers, it may be more convenient to use `values(crop(logoT, ext(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)))`

Answer (score 0):

I got a better solution, thanks to the `cellFromRowColCombine` function which makes the task simpler:

```
Cells <- cellFromRowColCombine(logoT, 35:(35+3-1), 50:(50+3-1))
extract(logoT[[2:3]], Cells)
```

No longer need for getValuesBlock.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Robert. Your solution is (of course!) much better, because much faster on execution. However, the behaviour of `readValues` is not easy to understand from the help page. After a few tests, I understood that it depends on the `SpatRaster` being or not in memory:

```
logo <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))
# the SpatRaster is in a file, no value returned
readValues(logo,row=35, nrows=3, col=50, ncols=3, mat=TRUE)
#   red green blue
 
logo2 <- logo*1
# the SpatRaster is in memory, readValues works
readValues(logo2,row=35, nrows=3, col=50, ncols=3, mat=TRUE)
#      red green blue
# [1,] 155   168  220
# [2,] 167   176  231
# [3,] 165   175  226
# ...
```

When the source is a file, the `SpatRaster` must be "opened" before:

```
logo <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))

readStart(logo)
readValues(logo,row=35, nrows=3, col=50, ncols=3, mat=TRUE)
#      red green blue
# [1,] 155   168  220
# [2,] 167   176  231
# [3,] 165   175  226
# ...
readStop(logo)
```

Is that wright? If so, perhaps this distinction between in file and in memory `SpatRaster` treatments should be mentioned somewhere in the help page `read and write`.

Also, it could be helpful to have a mention of `readValues` in the `extract` help page, as a `see also` function, because it is highly related (and more efficient, for extracting blocks).

Finally, the following script raises an error:

```
logo <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))
readValues(logo,row=35, nrows=3, col=50, ncols=3, mat=TRUE)
#   red green blue
 
readStart(logo)
# Error: [readStart] the file is not open for reading
```

The erroneous call to `readValues` seems to have a side effect on the following `readStart`, which should not be the case.